# Shortest possible route, starting and finishing anywhere

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I'm looking for an algorithm that will connect a large amount of geographic coordinates (100-1000), creating the shortest possible route between them, starting anywhere and finishing anywhere else. I'm working with Python.

I have researched the available algorithms, and my problem is similar to the Traveling Salesman, but it requires me to define a starting point, and will come back to this same point at the end. **I will be taking an Uber to any starting point and from any other ending point back home. What I want is to cover all points while walking as little as possible**. I don't care where it starts or ends.

Prim's and Kruskal's algorithms seem to find good starting and ending points, but they create a tree, not an optimized walking route as TSP.

Prim's algorithm:

[image: Prim's algorithm]

Kruskal's algorithm:

[image]

Desired outcome based on Prim/Kruskal, but using TSP logic (example drawn by hand, not optimized):

[image: Desired outcome]

Comment: i think since you have a metric case then each node should only be visited once in the optimal solution. Therefore you can do this:
for any pair of nodes u and v, generate a new graph:
* replace u and v with a new node w
* for any other node x, let the distance between x and w be minimum of x-> u and x-> v
Then the TSP result will have one incoming edge to w and one outgoing, you can separate it into a path. Choose the pair u, v that has the shortest path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need a productionized solution, write Python to dump your distance matrix in TSPLIB format with an extra city (representing the place that you will Uber to/from) with distance zero to each other city. Then feed it to (e.g.) [Concorde](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde.html) or [LKH](http://akira.ruc.dk/~keld/research/LKH/index-1.3.html).

Answer (score 2):

Prim and Kruskal are algorithms to find a spanning tree.  You're trying to solve a well-known variant of TS (the Traveling Salesman problem), in which you do not return to your starting point.

The location of your home is immaterial, per your definition.  Your defined problem is to visit every location with the least distance traveled, *without* returning to your starting point.  This is covered well in "the literature".

The "quick strike" solution is to take any standard TS solution and remove the longest segment.  This is a good heuristic, although it doesn't guarantee the optimal solution.

Comment: Measuring the distance between all points and using the furthest ones as start and finish points? Based on the example above, it indeed doesn't seem like the optimal solution.

Comment: No, that's not what I said.  You take a full-circuit TS solution.  Identify the longest segment of that solution, which is almost certainly *not* the two farthest points.  The endpoints of that longest segment would be your points.

Comment: However, the fact  that the length of that segment is included in the eval function for the TS solution, this is likely *not* the optimal solution, but merely a heuristic to get a *good* solution.

Comment: It worked well for some routes, but unfortunately very badly for others!

Comment: RIght: it's a heuristic, as I said.  You can make pathological cases.